# Долгая загрузка страницы

Tags: css, lazyloading

Всем привет! Очень долго подгружается страница, хотя скриптов нет и вообще страничка лёгкая, лишь несколько изображений в формате jpg. Кроме того, даже когда страница подгружена при скролле сперва показывается белый экран. Я что только не пробовал, кроме, разве что, lazy load. На хосте кэш включен. Подскажите, как справится с этой проблемой, в какую сторону думать?

Вот адрес странички: https://www.svetoch152.ru/

Answer (score 0):

Изображения на сайте в очень высоком разрешении (6к) когда само изображение занимает менее половины страницы.

При первой загрузке сайта, используется более 12мб трафика

[image: демонстрация]